# Create a dropdown for a field not in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm creating a cascading dropdown for selecting cities in my view, so I need to create the first one to select the state and the second one will be dynamically filled via AJAX.

How can I create the first one considering I don't have a state_id field in my view model (only city_id)?

And when loading the edit view, how can I load the same dropdown and select the right option even without having this value?

### UPDATE

For better understanding of what I have and what I need, here's some more information.

I have 3 tables:

**States**
id, 
name,
abbreviation

**Cities**
id,
name,
state_id

**Patients**
id,
name,
city_id

The idea is to have a states dropdown loaded automatically when editing or creating a new patient, and the cities dropdown will be loaded when an item is selected in the states dropdown.

I tried to use this code in my view:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= f.input :state, collection: @states %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <%= f.input :city_id %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

However, the :state doesn't exist, so causes an error.

Comment: you can always use attr_eccessor to utilize fields not attached to the model, but if you don't have a state.. how will you be able to populate cities that belong to that state?

Comment: I've added more info, hope it helps explaining the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make it a separate select field tied to a jQuery event that holds state data like so:

```
#Form

<select id="state_select">
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>

<%= label :city %>
<%= select :city, options_for_select([]) %>

#In Script
$("#state_select").on("change", function(ev) {

    //Set the city based on the state and append it to / overwrite the empty array in cities       

})
```